# Is there an "off the shelf" way to make magnesium ascorbate?

Tags: acid-base

I make my own sodium ascorbate with ascorbic acid and sodium bicarb. It's easy, I get the vitamin c off ebay and the baking soda from the store.

Is there a similar way to make magnesium ascorbate: ingredients easily available, room temp, etc?

Comment: Except as a grassroots science experiment (grow crystals?), what is this good for?

Comment: I assume a [milk of magnesia](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22milk+of+magnesia%22), what is essentially suspension of [Mg(OH)2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_hydroxide) is commercially available for per oral usage as antacid or laxative.

Comment: @Karl its a base for making liposomal C for personal use. Mg is typically more needed than Na in humans. Me especially ;)

Comment: @Poutnik interesting. I will try it. I suppose the reaction should be identical except swap a little H2 for the CO2 off-gassing? Anyway, make this comment an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @rickopps What about H2 ??

Comment: @Poutnik just asking if Milk of Magnesia + Ascorbic Acid would off-gas H2? I did take Chem 101 and 102, haha, but that's all, and that was long ago ;)

Comment: I would recommend starting to eat *wholesome* food instead of potentially poisoning yourself with trendy supplementals, but then of course I'm no authority on nutrition. Good luck.

Comment: @Karl Yes, I agree wholeheartedly, however the liposomal C is amazing stuff. I am a baker by trade, so I love "soft" chemistry... making liposomal C is easy and fun to me, and it is crazy effective.

Comment: @RickOpps Thanks, but ... how is it "effective"? Effective in doing *what*? (Btw., baking is *great* applied chemistry. +1)

Comment: @Karl I mean as a Vitamin C in general, liposomal is more effective. Any other vitamin C is thought to be 10% to 20% available through the digestive system. It's easy to take enough C to give yourself diarrhea. But liposomal C is thought to be about 80% available. This is also my personal experience. It is very difficult to take liposomal C to "bowl tolerance". So, if you are into C, a Linus Pauling reader, etc. Liposomal C is a beautiful thing.

Comment: Linus Pauling had become a senile idiot when he was promoting vitamin C. His earlier scientific work was excellent and got him a nobel price, his taking a political stand against nuclear armament was admirable and got him the second one, but after that he turned into a pitiful pseudoscientist, which, out of respect for his achievements, I put down to senility. Can happen to anyone.

Comment: @Karl, well, lol, okay then. For others who happen upon this rabbit trail and are interested in this idiocy, please also look up Dr. Rhonda Patrick. She might be a senile idiot too? Who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume a [milk of magnesia](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22milk%20of%20magnesia%22), what is essentially suspension of [Mg(OH)2](http://Mg(OH)2) is commercially available for per oral usage as antacid or laxative.

Mixing with ascorbic acid solution will produce water and magnesium ascorbate.